# Remotely call getinfo from bitcoin server

Tags: client

doing a bit of research on what versions of bitcoin client nodes are using, i have a long list of clients connected to the network, i was wondering what is the best way to get the version - is there a way / script where i can connect to the nodes and request the getinfo packet from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to run your own node, and then call [`getpeerinfo`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getpeerinfo) on it.  This will give you a list of all the connected peers, including information like the reported version.  You can also use the `addnode` option to ensure that you attempt to connect to all the nodes in your list.